# Job control over a Bash script

Tags: shell-script, ffmpeg, job-control

I have a Bash script of a thousand lines each containing an `ffmpeg` command. I start this with `source script` and it runs just fine.

However, when I try to take control of this script in various ways, things go completely awry:

- If I do `Ctrl + Z` to pause the whole thing, only the *current* `ffmpeg` command is paused, and the *next one* is started! Not what I wanted!
- If I do `Ctrl + C` to stop everything, the script jumps to the next `ffmpeg` command, and I have to press once for every line in the script to
  finally stop everything. Sheer hell.
- I tried using `ps -ef` from another shell to locate the `source` command to pause/kill it from there, but it does not exist in the list.

So how can I pause/stop the parent script the way I wish? Or possibly, how can I execute the script in a different way to begin with that gives me the proper control over it?

Comment: By the way, we Unix & Linux people don't use the phrase "batch file".

Comment: Nitpicking adhered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try running the script as a script instead of sourcing it:

```
$ bash <scriptname>
```

Comment: So simple! Now everything behaves exactly as desired. So when should one use `source` and `bash` respectively?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that `ffmpeg` catches the `SIGINT` – signal sent by <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> – but it is ignored in bash as it does not know if the signal is intended for it as well.

One remedy for this is to add a *trap* for the signal in the script and handle it locally.

For example add a trap to start of file with commands. Then make it executable and run it, or by 
`$ bash script_file` - ***not `source`***:

```
trap 'exit' INT
```

A more fancy line which abort with message and [exit status 130](http://www.museum.state.il.us/ismdepts/library/linuxguides/abs-guide/exitcodes.html):

```
trap 'printf "Received SIGINT: Terminating.\n";exit 130' INT
```

Then:

```
$ ./file_with_commands
```

---

Or a sourcing killer script:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'printf "Received SIGINT: Terminating.\n";exit 130' INT

source "$1"
```

Then:

```
$ ./sourcetrap file_with_commands
```

---

A simple example script could be:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 = trap ]]; then
    trap 'printf "Received SIGINT: Terminating.\n";exit 130' INT
fi

ping localhost
ping localhost
ping localhost
```

- Run without trap: `./script_name`
- With trap: `./script_name trap`

Then <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> to witness the difference.

---

And again; do not *`source`* these scripts from terminal prompt.

Comment: OK, I know that `--` insulates you against the possibility that the next word *might* begin with **`-`**, but is there any reason to use it when you know what the next word is, and it does not begin with **`-`**?

Comment: Also, you should warn the user to disable the SIGINT → `exit` trap immediately upon termination of the script; otherwise, the next time he types (Ctrl)+(C) at a shell prompt (i.e., when he doesn't have a command running in the foreground), the shell will exit.

Comment: @Scott: Comment 1: `--` no reason. Comment 2: This would, AFAIK, only be an issue if he uses `source`, which I told *not* to do.

Comment: Very interesting! I will experiment with this signal handling!